# Adding a restriction to network analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I currently have some shapefiles regarding flooding that I want to use as restrictions for my network analysis, however, I don't know how to use them. I know I'm able to draw restrictions, but I want to be able to use my shapefiles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [restriction polygon barriers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/barriers.htm). You will be able to load the polygons of your flooding zones as polygon barriers. This will "close" those road links that will within those areas.

Image from Esri Help:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Restrictions need to be part of the gdb you are developing the network in.
See also: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm

Comment: Surely there must be a way without adding the shapefiles to the gdb?

Comment: Nope there isn't. If you have read the tutorial you've learned that the only way to make a route network is within a GDB.